# $\eta(I)=m(I)$ for a generic pluri-interval $I$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\eta$ be a measure on the Borel algebra (generated by the open sets in $\mathbb R^n$) $\mathcal B$ such that

1. $\eta([0,1]^n)=1$;
2. $\eta(A+y)=\eta(A)$, $\forall A\in \mathcal B$, $\forall y\in\mathbb R^n$;
3. $\eta(\lambda A)=\lambda^n\eta(A)$, $\forall A\in\mathcal B$ $\forall \lambda>0$;

I have to show that the lebesgue measure $\mu$ is such that $\mu(I)=\eta(I)$, for every pluri-interval in $\mathbb R^n$.

My idea was this: If I consider an interval of the form $[\alpha,\beta]\subseteq \mathbb R$ and a measure $\bar \eta$, with the same properties of $\eta$, but defined in $\mathbb R$, I could write $[\alpha,\beta]$ as $\lambda[0,1]+y$,and, since $\bar\eta(A+y)=\bar\eta(A)$, I'd get $\bar\eta([\alpha,\beta])=\bar\eta(\lambda[0,1]+y)=\bar\eta(\lambda[0,1])$. The number $\lambda $ could be chosen as the lenght of the interval (respect to the euclidean metric) $\lambda=l([\alpha,\beta])=|\beta-\alpha|$ (?).
If I now extend this idea to a generic interval in $\mathbb R^n$, I can write a generic interval $H=[\alpha_1,\beta_1]\times\dots\times [\alpha_n,\beta_n]$ as
$(\lambda_1[0,1]+y_1)\times  \dots\times (\lambda_n[0,1]+y_n)$, where $\lambda_j=l([\alpha_j,\beta_j])\in\mathbb R$ , $j=1,\dots,n$ and $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)\in\mathbb R^n$.
Now, since $\eta$ preserves the measure of sets obtained by translation so $$\eta(H)=\eta([\alpha_1,\beta_1]\times\dots\times [\alpha_n,\beta_n])=\eta((\lambda_1[0,1]+y_1)\times\dots\times (\lambda_n[0,1]+y_n))=\eta((\lambda_1[0,1]\times\dots\times\lambda_n[0,1])+y)=\eta(\lambda_1[0,1]\times\dots\times\lambda_n[0,1]),$$ 
is there a way to conclude the proof? Should I've followed a completely different way to show this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the best way to show this, but I will suggest an outline of what I think is easiest to me.

(I) You need to show this only for pluri-intervals contained in $[0,1]^n$ of the form $\prod_{j=1}^n [0,r_j]$, where $0\leq r_j\leq 1$ for all $j$.

(II) Show that $\eta$ assigns $0$ values for pluri-interval with one side being of length $0$. This should be showed using $1.$, $2.$ and sub-additivity of $\eta$.

(III) Since any number can be written by a dyadic expansion, it is enough to show this for a pluri-interval of the form

$$ B=\prod_{j=1}^n \Big[0, \frac{q_j}{2^{m_j}} \Big] \quad \text{where} \quad 1 \leq q_j \leq 2^{m_j}. $$

(IV) Using $3.$ , you know that

$$\eta \Bigg( \prod_{j=1}^n \Big[0, \frac{1}{2^{m}} \Big] \Bigg)= \Big( \frac{1}{2^m} \Big)^n. $$
Therefore using translation invariance, you get by $2.$ that

$$ \eta(B)= \eta \Bigg(  \Big[0, \frac{1}{2^{max_{1\leq j\leq n} \{m_j\}}} \Big]^n \Bigg) \cdot \prod_{j=1}^n q_j\cdot 2^{max_{1\leq j\leq n} \{m_j\} -m_j}=m(B). $$

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for your time! I don't really undestand the step III because I think we've never seen that kind of construction at lesson. Anyway, I think it's a quite standard method to proceed for this type of exercises.

Comment: @Alchemist Well, if $r_j=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a^{(j)}_k \cdot 2^{-k}$, then you can say that $B:=\prod_{j=1}^n \Big[0, \frac{q_j}{2^{m_j}} \Big] \quad \text{where} \quad 1 \leq q_j \leq 2^{m_j}$, has measure $\lim \eta\Big(  \big[ 0, \sum_{k=1}^N a^{(j)}_k \cdot 2^{-k} \big]  \times [0,1]^{n-1} \Big)=\eta(B)$ by continuity from below.